# Jquery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a jquery question here , i have some dynamic html links on my page and once a link is get clicked it should open a dialog box using jquery , the problem is that i am not sure about the no of links as they are dynamic generating through php while loop so i cannot provide different id's to those links and target them individually , i want a way so that any of the link is clicked it should open a dialog box no matter even if they all same id or class.

Let me know if you want me to be more specific.

Thank You

Comment: Should the dialog boxes be unique?

Comment: no they all would be same but all links will have same id or class

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically generate the content you always could have a `<div>` inside the dialog and fill it with `.html(contents);`

Answer (score 0):

With same class

```
$('a.your_class').click(function(){
   //your code for dialog
});
```

This wont work with the same id's, because jquery will return only first result, because ID should be unique on whole page.

for every link

```
$('a').click(function() {
   //your dialog here
});
```

for links in specific container

```
$('#container a').click(function() {
  //your code for dialog
});
```

Just make sure that the code needs to be places into

$(document).ready(function()
{
  //your code here, this will execute code when page is loaded
});

Comment: but it is only doing for the first link not for rest of them i have also tried jquery each function that doesn't seems working too

Comment: it will do for every link on page

Comment: but in that way all of my links on the page will start generating dialog boxes that what i dnt want i want to target those links with specific id let say <a id="link"> and i have 10 of those with same id's

Comment: so just assign class, class that doesn't exists like class="dialogopener" and use it for links that should open dialog

Comment: You can assign multiple classes to element by separating them with the space like this class="class_one class_to class_three"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery live function for binding to elements that may not exist yet.

http://api.jquery.com/live

I would use live to bind to the links via a class name. When the link is clicked wire up the dialog and open it. Something like this...

```
$(".some_class").live("click", function(event){

    $(this).dialog(options); //create the dialog
    $(this).dialog("open"); //open the dialog
});
```

Comment: yup that seems to be helpfull Bzink

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your click event to something that will be consistent to the links you're dynamically generating. For example, if you give your links a class of "dialog-link" then you can do a selector for that specific class.

```
$('a.dialog-link').click(function(){
//Do something
});
```

If the links are dynamically appended to your dom via javascript after pageLoad, then you have to delegate the click with live.

```
$('a.dialog-link').live('click',function(){
//Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(foo).dialog({ autoOpen: false })`

will create your dialog, and

```
$('a.opendialog').live('click',function() {
    $(foo).dialog('open'); 
    return false;
}
```

will open it every time you click any link with the "opendialog" class added to it.